# Android Teamcity error: "The system cannot find the file specified"

Tags: continuous-integration, teamcity, android-build

I started setting up Teamcity for my Android project. I am doing this for the first time. I am getting this error in the build step:

> C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\5466jhg2a9111046\local.properties (The
> system cannot find the file specified)

What does this error mean?

Comment: I run into same thing. I have teamcity in docker. One project is working other is not. I tried everything nothing seems to help. Have you found any solution? Thanks

Comment: I uploaded my --stacktrace log to https://pastebin.com/M0W79Eng

Answer (score 0):

In my case, someone included plugin that need local.properties.

`com.google.android.libraries.mapsplatform.secrets-gradle-plugin`

> Google strongly recommends that you not check an API key into your version control system. Instead, you should store it in the local.properties file, which is located in the root directory of your project and then use the Secrets Gradle Plugin for Android to read the API key.

This plugin was looking for `local.properties` and that was not successful. I recommned you checking all project level `build.gradle` dependencies. One of them might require `local.properties`.

If you really need `local.properties` to be present, you can create `Command Line` build step which can create `local.properties` for you with all required paramters. But there might be also better way to do this.